# RSS feed to include total reputation points

Tags: discussion, reputation, rss

I know I can use this feed

> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/[site]/users/[userid]/reputation

to get changes in reputation as well as the reason for change, but it returns change only.

Is there something similar that would return actual reputation value?

Comment: Damn there's no bounty on Meta.

Comment: +1 for you. Let's see if this will raise awareness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it.

This

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/[userid]?site=[site]
```

Outputs a nice JSON result. I.e. for me it's

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/961695?site=stackoverflow

What you do with JSON after that - sky's the limit. I used https://zapier.com service to push updates to https://pushover.net/ and ultimately to my Pebble watch.

[image]
[image]

Also using [Pushover API with jQuery to read/write notifications](http://codecorner.galanter.net/2014/05/21/how-to-receive-stack-overflow-notifications-on-your-phone-and-smartwatch-v-2-0/)