# Stack Overflow RSS feed with user details

Tags: discussion, rss

I am using the RSS feed for Stack Overflow and writing my own parser. All is OK but I would like to get more details about the user posting the question.

Is it possible to get the user details, more specifically the user reputation, via a simple unauthenticated query?

If at all possible I'd like to avoid using the APIs in favor of a simple HTTP GET.

Comment: Asked the same question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253783/rss-feed-to-include-total-reputation-points plz let me know if you find the answer

Comment: I think I got it. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254732/961695

Comment: That's it. Too bad I can't promote a comment to an answer.